# ORACLE - How to count the number of occurrences of a member in a collection?

Tags: oracle, collections, count

If I had a collection in Oracle like this:

```
DECLARE
    TYPE v_type IS TABLE OF varchar2(4000);
    v_coll v_type := v_type();
    v_num_dups NUMBER;
BEGIN
    v_coll.extend();
    v_coll(1):= 'not dupe';
    v_coll.extend();
    v_coll(2):= 'dupe';
    v_coll.extend();
    v_coll(3):= 'dupe';

    for i in 1..v_coll.count loop
        dbms_output.put_line(v_coll(i));
    end loop;

END;
```

How could I return the count of `dupe` occurrences into `v_num_dups` without looping through the collection and counting?

Is there some simple way to say `v_coll.count('dupe')` or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to avoid duplicates entirely, you could use an associative array.  Something like:

```
DECLARE
    TYPE v_type IS TABLE OF number index by varchar2(4000);
    v_coll v_type;
    idx varchar2(4000);
BEGIN
    v_coll('not dupe'):= 1;
    v_coll('dupe'):= 1;
    v_coll('dupe'):= 1;

    -- show key values 
    idx := v_coll.first;
    loop
      exit when idx is null;
      dbms_output.put_line(idx);
      idx := v_coll.next(idx);
    end loop;

END;
```

Output:

```
dupe
not dupe
```

Comment: wow, this is great... any duplicate just gets pointed to the last value that was previously added. I guess its bad if you *want* duplicate values, but if not, this is awesome! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't (at least as of 11g). 
You have to iterate through the collection manually and perform the count.

Answer (score 0):

While I like `tbone`'s answer, this also works VERY nice to remove duplicates:

```
DECLARE
    TYPE v_type IS TABLE OF varchar2(4000);
    v_coll v_type := v_type();
    v_num_dups NUMBER;
BEGIN
    v_coll.extend();
    v_coll(1):= 'not dupe';
    v_coll.extend();
    v_coll(2):= 'dupe';
    v_coll.extend();
    v_coll(3):= 'dupe';

    v_coll:=SET(v_coll); --<----remove dups!

    dbms_output.put_line(cardinality(v_coll));

    for i in 1..v_coll.count loop
        dbms_output.put_line(v_coll(i));
    end loop;

END;
```

Comment: it is nice but VERY slow on big volumes... ;-) When you are using method suggested by tbone (the best method I think) be aware of null values. If you assigne null as a key your loop will stop working correctly.